# Java 8 stream group by multiple attributes and sum

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects as the folowing and I want to group them by 3 attributes and sum the 4th ones

```
public class DTO {
    private final  String at1;
    private final  String at2;
    private final  Integer at3;
    private final  BigDecimal amount;

}
```

I did something like the folowing but it results in many Maps and I couldn't get a way to sum amounts as it requires some logic as well

```
List<DTO> list = ...
Map<String, Map<String, Map<Integer, List<DTO>>>> groupedItems =
                list.stream()
                .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getAt1(), 
                    Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getAt2(),
                                Collectors.groupingBy( e -> e.getAt3()))));
```

How can I get a list of grouped list with sum logic?

Comment: What would be your expected result data structure? As I understand you do not want the Maps. Do you want Map<DTO, Integer>? And group together the DTOs that have all 3 properties with equal values?

Comment: yes I want to group the DTOs that have all 3 properties with equal values, and return list of DTOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a constructor which hold the three attributes that you want to group with:

```
public DTO(String at1, String at2, Integer at3) {
    this.at1 = at1;
    this.at2 = at2;
    this.at3 = at3;
}
```

and then you can use:

```
Map<DTO, BigDecimal> groupedItems = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> new DTO(e.getAt1(), e.getAt2(), e.getAt3()),
                Collectors.reducing(
                        BigDecimal.ZERO,
                        DTO::getAmount,
                        BigDecimal::add)));
```

I assume you are overriding `equals` and `hashCode` in DTO class.

---

Example:

```
List<DTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new DTO("a", "b", 1, BigDecimal.valueOf(10)));
list.add(new DTO("z", "y", 4, BigDecimal.valueOf(20)));
list.add(new DTO("a", "b", 1, BigDecimal.valueOf(30)));
list.add(new DTO("a", "b", 1, BigDecimal.valueOf(40)));
```

Outputs

```
DTO{at1='a', at2='b', at3=1, amount=null} - 80
DTO{at1='z', at2='y', at3=4, amount=null} - 20
```

Comment: I remember a quote that Jamie Zawinski, the co-author of XEmacs once said about regex: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' Regex is obsolete. Stream is in. And some people get TWO problems when they think Stream is the omnipotent solution.

Comment: from OP's comment *... and return list of DTOs* , `toMap` with a merge function and values extracted could have been better...anyway the assumption is that, equals and hashcode on the primary attributes.